# Linq Performance: (ElementAt,Count) vs (foreach)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I iterate through an IEnumerable as the result of a Linq query using (ElementAt,Count) and (foreach).  To my surprise, the performance difference is 25-30 fold!  Why is that?

```
IEnumerable<double> result =
     ... simple Linq query that joins two tables
     ... returns about 600 items

double total = 0;

// Method 1: iterate with Count and ElementAt
for( int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++ )
{
    total += result.ElementAt(i);
}

// Method 2: iterate with foreach
foreach( double value in result )
{
    total += value;
}
```

Comment: Which way round is the difference (what's faster)?

Comment: `Count()` will iterate over the whole enumerable. Each `ElementAt(n)` will iterate to the nth element. `foreach` will iterate the whole enumerable once. I don't know all optimizations if the enumerable is also an `IList` or `ICollection`.

Comment: You should clearly state which method was faster

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ElementAt()` method is O(n), unless the actual concrete class that the `IEnumerable` represents optimizes it. That means that every time you call it, it has to loop through the entire Enumerable to find the element at `n`. Not to mention that since you have `i < result.Count()` in the condition part of your `for` loop, it's gotta loop through the entire enumerable every single time to get that count.

The second way, you loop through `result` exactly once.

Comment: Since they say it's from a join, I'd guess that result.Count() is actually turned into a `SQL COUNT(*)`. Hardly an improvement though!

Answer (score 6):

Because `ElementAt` is iterating through the `IEnumerable` every time you call it. `IEnumerable`s are not indexed so `ElementAt` must be implemented using `GetEnumerator()`.

Why not do

```
total = result.Sum();
```

Comment: ... as is `Count()`. There's no need for the lambda expression, btw. Just `result.Sum()` should be fine.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, suspected so but had to go and check first. Seems obvious now, ala `Select()`

Comment: `total += p;` is for demostration purpose.  The actual logic is different.

Answer (score 1):

Because each call iterates over the list. The simple solution is to call .ToList() before iterating, a better solution is to stop iterating.

```cs
var theList = result.ToList();

for( int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++ )
{
    total += result[i];
}
```

Better solution:

```
total = result.Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference is due to the fact the `IEnumerable` doesn't allow you to get by index, so every time you call `ElementAt` in your first loop it has to iterate through every item until it gets to the element you requested.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about understanding deferred execution! When a query is executed several times, then the time to run increases dramatically. LINQ can be quicker, but you really need to make a choice based on how you're going to use your query results.

Take a look at this article http://allthingscs.blogspot.com/2011/03/linq-performance.html. It analyzes that very issue .

Answer (score 0):

If i were to hazard a guess, the result.Count() call is non-deferred and actually hits the database whereas the foreach does not. If you flip the order you may get the opposite result. Also you could just do `total = result.Sum();`

Answer (score 0):

The first may be equivalent to:

```
double total = 0;

int i = 0;
while(true)
{
  int max = /*Database call to obtain COUNT(*) of join*/
  if(max > i)
    break;
  int j = 0;
  foreach(double value in result)
  {
    if(j++ == i)
    {
      total += value;
      break;
    }
  }
  ++i
}
```

Or it could even be equivalent to:

```
double total = 0;

int i = 0;
while(true)
{
  int max = 0;
  foreach(double value in result)
    ++max;
  if(max > i)
    break;
  int j = 0;
  foreach(double value in result)
  {
    if(j++ == i)
    {
      total += value;
      break;
    }
  }
  ++i
}
```

Or it could even requery to get `result` each time it appers in the code above.

On the other hand, `Count()` *could* be obtained by one property access, and `ElementAt()` could be O(1), if these are backed on structures that allow for such an optimisation, and such an optimisation was indeed available (e.g. it is for `List<T>`).